# In CSS, can "#footer #caption" coexist with "#content #caption"?

Tags: css, stylesheet, styles, sass, nested

I was going to "nest" the CSS `id`s like this

```
#content #caption { color: teal }
  ...

#footer #caption { margin: 2em 1em }
```

because that's the way SASS (a CSS generator) can do nesting for... but then in one HTML document, we cannot have two `id`s with the same name, isn't that true, so the above nesting won't work or won't work well.  (esp if document.getElementById() or $('#caption') or $('caption') is needed to select the element).

We can use

```
#content #content_caption { color: teal }
  ...

#footer #footer_caption { margin: 2em 1em }
```

but then why 1 more level of nesting?  why not just

```
#content_caption { color: teal }
  ...

#footer_caption { margin: 2em 1em }
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "caption" would indicate that it is not an unique identifier. If so, I would declare the caption as a class. The following would be completely legal and valid:

```
#content .caption { color: teal }
#footer .caption { margin: 2em 1em }
```

Comment: that looks good, although by using classes extensively, it is not really what is called the "CSS classitis"?

Comment: Of course, you never have to use this too much. It is maybe even better to use headings if it seems logical. Then you can match on h1 or h2.

Answer (score 1):

no reason for that. id is a really heavy selector, it should be enough to change the styling rules. if not append the #content before or change the selectors of the rules that are winning.

Comment: what do you mean "heavy"?  in what ways?

Comment: for example: #test{color: red} div{color: green} <div id="test">asdf</div> now asdf is red because red rule has a much more powerful selector. ids get 100 points classes 10 and elements 1 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This "points" explanation never made sense to me because 11 classes is still lower than an id. You have to think of them as separate things, you can't add them together. The general idea of "points" is just for illustration.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no two elements with id="caption" on the single page, it's perfectly OK.
However, I guess from the naming (content & footer) that there's more than one with id = "caption", which is very bad. You should remember that **id *must* be unique!** Use "class" instead, like

```
#content .caption { }
#footer .caption { }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, something like "caption" really does sound more like a class:

You say: **this is **the** footer** (specific id), but **this is **a** caption** (general class).

Here's another way you can nest the selectors in Sass:

```
.caption
  margin: 2em 1em
  font-weight: bold
  #footer &
    background: teal
  #content &
    background: red
```

(The "&" references whatever it's contained in.)